# emacs reftex reftex-create-bibtex-file ignores cites with optional arguments

Tags: emacs, auctex

Emacs reftex has a command `reftex-create-bibtex-file` that searches the current .tex file and creates a bibliography (`.bib`) of all cited works. The problem is, that while it picks up `\cite{foo}` it doesn't spot `\cite[bar]{foo}` which is annoying. Is there a way to make this function recognise (and ignore) option arguments on cite macros?

Comment: http://old.nabble.com/4.33--%28reftex-create-bibtex-file%29-bug-or-missing-feature.-td31740959.html refers to the same problem. I guess this problems can be solved if one manages to redefine the regexp in the function such that `[bar]` is optional between `\cite` and `{foo}`. I tried to find the definition of the function by `find-function` but it fails